# Is it possible to use google signin with react-native-web?

Tags: react-native, google-signin, react-native-web

We're building a react-native application which has a Google Signin powered by [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin). This library uses native functionality which is not available in the web, so my expectation is that it is not possible to port our react-native application to the web.

Is it possible to use google signin with react-native-web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-native-web tries to provide DOM based implementation of react-native elements and it is mostly UI focused.

It is possible to use google signin but you will have to use web integration of google signin https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

You can also try https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login or any other equivalent web libraries

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed what I expected.

Comment: Note that Google SDK is being replaced with https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web in 2023